# Quotient rule application with negative in front

Tags: calculus

Consider the following function:
$$
Y=Z-\frac{b(x)}{g(x)}
$$
I want to compute $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}$. The document am
looking at has it as:
$$
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}=\frac{g'b-b'g}{g^{2}}
$$
I don't think this is quite correct. Should it not be
$$
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}=-\left(\frac{g'b-b'g}{g^{2}}\right)
$$
owing to the presence of the $-$ in front of the ratio?

Comment: It is correct. Apply the quotient rule yourself and note the order is reversed in the numerator, which the minus sign takes care of.